# How can one find the possible Jordan forms for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2 = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find all the possible Jordan normal forms for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2 = 0$.

If I have any $2 \times 2$ matrix, I can have either have one eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$ or two different eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$.  I don't see how $A^2 = 0$ would make it any different?  Which possibility can I eliminate and why?

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan normal form has blocks of the shape $$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda&1&0&0\\
0&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
0&0&\lambda&1\\
0&0&0&\lambda
\end{array}\right]$$

For 2x2 matrix you have 2 possibilities:

1. 2 blocks of $1 \times 1$ each which would just be $[\lambda]$.
2. 1 block of $2\times 2$ which would be $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \lambda&1\\
   0&\lambda\\
   \end{array}\right]$

Now maybe it gets easier.

Answer (score 1):

$A^2 = 0$ tells you that your characteristic polynomial is $x^2$. Since the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, this tells you that your minimal polynomial has to be either $x$ or $x^2$.

Case 1: Min poly = $x$.

In this case we have that $A = 0$ and is already in Jordan Form.

Case 2: Min poly = $x^2$.

In this case the Jordan Form is $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

Comment: That's the Jordan block, the Jordan form you need to multiply by some arbitrary $S$, $S^{-1}$ left and right respectively.

Comment: @mathreadler No, this specific matrix is what we call the Jordan Form. Conjugating this matrix by all invertible matrices would give you the set of all matrices similar to $A$...

Comment: Okay, that's not what I learned to call it. I learned to call the whole setup $A = SJS^{-1}$ the Jordan (canonical) form, but maybe I learned wrong then.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. I think most people would refer to the matrix $J$ as the Jordan Form. That said, the coordinate change of base matrix $S$ is important too! Note that in this problem, we don't have enough information to compute $S$.

Answer (score 1):

One can take advantage of the *small* size of the matrix in question.

The condition $A^2=0$ tells you that the only possible eigenvalue is $\lambda=0$. Thus the only possible Jordan forms for $A$ are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now one can check immediately that any matrix $B$ similar to any one of them satisfies $B^2=0$.

---

If you are considering larger size matrices, the general [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2062782/9464) would be the minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Let J be the Jordan canonical form for A. Then there exists an invertible matrix M such that

> A = M<sup>-1</sup>* J * M

Then

> A<sup>2</sup> = (M<sup>-1</sup>* J * M) * (M<sup>-1</sup>* J * M) = M<sup>-1</sup>* J<sup>2</sup> * M = **0**

Suppose there is some nonzero eigenvalue λ of A. Then either λ is the only eigenvalue or there is some other (possibly zero) eigenvalue λ<sub>o</sub>.

> Case 1: J = $\begin{bmatrix}λ & 1\\0 & λ \end{bmatrix}$
>
> > J<sup>2</sup> = $\begin{bmatrix}λ^2  & 2λ\\0 & λ^2 \end{bmatrix}$ = **0**
> > ==> λ = 0, which is a contradiction.
>
> Case 2: J = $\begin{bmatrix}λ & 0\\0 & λo \end{bmatrix}$
>
> > J<sup>2</sup> = $\begin{bmatrix}λ^2 & 0\\0 & λo^2 \end{bmatrix}$ = **0**
> > ==> λ = 0, which is a contradiction.

So there can be no non-zero eigenvalue of A. Therefore the only two possible Jordan canonical forms for A are
J = $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ or J = **0**.

In the latter case, J = **0** implies A = M<sup>-1</sup> * J * M = **0**. Note that in general, for an nxn matrix A such that A<sup>n</sup> = **0**, the Jordan canonical form of A must be composed solely of Jordan blocks with eigenvalue 0. By the same reasoning above, A<sup>n</sup> = **0** implies J<sup>n</sup> = **0**. If J is represented in block diagonal form, then we see that every block raised to the n<sup>th</sup> power is the zero matrix. Suppose we have some block J<sub>λ</sub> of size greater than one. Then J<sub>λ</sub><sup>n</sup> will have λ<sup>n</sup> along the diagonals, so J<sub>λ</sub><sup>n</sup> = **0** implies λ = 0.